# How to set maximum size of a Multipart with annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My goal is to store and get a profile picture.

How to store:

1. User send a form data to POST /account

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("fullname", "John Wick");
let profile_picture = new File(["foo"], "foo.txt", {
  type: "text/plain",
}); // for simplicity, I use .txt
formData.append("profile_picture", profile_picture);
```

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {
  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<String> postAccount(AccountDto accountDto) {
    // do something
  }
}

class AccoutnDto {
  private String profile_picture;
  private String fullname;

  public void getProfile_Picture() {
    return profile_picture;
  }
  
  // I wish to add javax.constraints or else to prevent upload / download size larger than 128KB.
  public void setProfile_Picture(MultipartFile profile_picture) {
    this.profile_picture = profile_picture;
  }

  public void getFullname() {
    return fullname;
  }

  public void setFullname(String fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
  }
}
```

How to download:

1. User send a GET /profile_picture

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {
  @GetMapping("/profile_picture")
  public ResponseEntity<Resource> getAccount() {
    Resource file = // do something...
    return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
            "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"").body(file);
  }
}
```

My current solution is to add a global configuration in application.yml

```
spring.servlet.multipart:
  max-file-size: 128KB
  max-request-size: 128KB
```

My expected result is: The max-file-size and max-request-size only applies to POST /account and GET /profile_picture.

My actual result is: Other MultipartFile object is affected.